# Merge two arrays with equal number of objects into one array

Tags: jquery, arrays, merge

I have two arrays filled with objects, it looks as so:

*ArrayYear*:

```
Array [ year: "1977", year: "1980"... ]
Object { year: "1977" }
```

*ArrayMeal*:

```
Array [ meal: "carrot", meal: "beef"... ]
Object { meal: "carrot" }
```

**How do I merge the two arrays to one that looks as so?**

```
Array [ {year: "1977", meal: "carrot"}, {year: "1980", meal: "beef"}... ]
```

The two arrays are populated as so:

```
arrayYear = [];
$('.item-year').each(function(index){
    arrayYear.push({ year: $(this).attr('data-year') });
})

arrayMeal = [];
$('.item-meal').each(function(index){
    arrayMeal.push({ meal: $(this).attr('data-meal') });
})
```

Comment: What does the actual arrayYear and arrayMeal look like? I am confused with your description of them.

Comment: tried adding some more info, not sure if it helps

Comment: The "arrays" you show are not valid javascript arrays.  Do you mean the arrays look like `["1977","1980", ...]`?

Answer (score 0):

Basic idea is to loop through and concat the objects together. With the help of jQuery, we can use extend.

```js
var ArrayYear = [ { year: "1977" }, {year: "1977" }];
var ArrayMeal = [ { meal: "carrot" }, {meal: "beef" }];

var array = ArrayYear.map( function (obj, index) {
    return $.extend({}, obj, ArrayMeal[index]);
});
console.log(array);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Now with what you posted, there is no need to build the two arrays unless you need it.

```
var years = $('.item-year');

var arrayOut = [];
$('.item-meal').each(function(index){
    arrayOut.push({ meal: $(this).attr('data-meal'), year : years.eq(index).attr('data-year') });
});
```

Could use map() there also instead of creating a new array.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you want to extend an object. To do so, jQuery has a method called [`.extend`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/). But there is one problem here, you have an array of object...

To solve this issue, you have to loop the array. You can use this code (read comments to understand each lines):

```js
// Assign first array
var arr1=[{year:1992},{year:1996},{year:2000}];
// Assign second array
var arr2=[{meat:'beef'},{meat:'porc'},{meat:'chicken'},{meat:'robot'}]; 

// Declare the resulting array (prevent from alterring the original arrays)
var merged_arr = []

// Loop the array
// We use Math.max so it work if 1 array has more items
for(var i = 0; i < Math.max(arr1.length, arr2.length); i++){
    // Set merged_arr cell's 1 to a new object which is a merge of both objects
    // First arg is an empty object so no arrays are alterred
    merged_arr[i] = $.extend({}, arr1[i], arr2[i]);
}

// Alert the result
alert(JSON.stringify(merged_arr))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since they are the same length you probably don't need to create both arrays and can do it once in your current loop of the DOM by matching the elements indexing

```
var $meals=$('.item-meal');

var fullArray = $('.item-year').map(function(idx){
    return {
       year: $(this).data('year') ,
       meal: $meals.eq(idx).data('meal')
    }
}).get();
```

This assumes that you are only creating the original arrays for the purpose of merging them afterwards

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/j2b80bLe/)**</kbd>